# Need to add a record into SQL if it not exists with in 90 days and if exists with in 90 days it need to be avoided

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[enter image description here][1]

I just want to take the new record so that it must pass the condition that if it exists with in 90 days it must not insert into table and if it doesn't exists with in 90 days then that particular record need to be inserted into the table.

I have written the query as following:

```
select * 
from driver 
where CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 90 > (select max(Createddate) 
                                from Driver 
                                where DriverID = '1x123' 
                                group by DriverID)
```

See the screenshot:

Comment: What happens when you run the query in the question?

Comment: Please resize your screenshot.

Comment: INSERT..SELECT..WHERE NOT EXISTS(..)

Comment: @DanBracuk It didn't show the output

Comment: @TabAlleman Can you briely write the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a pretty straightforward condition to test.  See the below self-contained example:

```
declare @tmp table(driverid nvarchar(10),createddate datetime)

--insert a sample record first
insert into @tmp
select '7x123','2015-6-20'


declare @incomingvalue nvarchar(10) = '7x123';

declare @now datetime = getdate();
declare @threshold datetime = @now - 90;

if exists(select * from @tmp where driverid = @incomingvalue and createddate >= @threshold)
begin
  print 'Already a record on file within 90 days, no action taken';
end
else
begin
  insert into @tmp
  select @incomingvalue, @now
  print 'Nothing on file in last 90 days, record inserted';
end

select * from @tmp
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working.

Comment: Since you use `datetime` rather than `date` for `@threshold` it will check the time-of-day, not just the date. That may or may not be the OP's intent. It is worth noting that this needs to be wrapped in a suitable transaction to avoid two users passing the `exists` test "simultaneously" and then both inserting rows.

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you are looking?

```
select '1x123', GetDate() 
where not exists ( select 1 
                     from driver  
                    where DateDiff(dd, Createddate, GetDate()) < 90 
                      and DriverID = '1x123' )
```

Comment: Hey @frisbee thanks for the query it is executing

Comment: You can click the check mark to indicate it was a proper answer

Comment: If I don't have a ID known then what approach I have to do with in that case the id's are same thats all we know so in that case can you come up with an query.

Comment: If you don't have a known ID then how is the accepted answer working?  This is just a shorter version of the accepted answer (as far as I can tell).

Comment: thanks for the answer and there isn't any other way that I can say even your answer was true so please don't mind in not mentioning your answer as correct@frisbee

Comment: hey @Frisbee I got proper answer from you in my earlier question  but here I gave an assumption if the there are two identical values the query must check for latest and which exceeds 90 days need to be shown in my result and the record which is within 90 days time period must not  be shown during my query execution. that was my scenario present. So earlier I have hard coded the ID value now in this case i must check the whole table and then need to provide the result.

Comment: So this is a new question?   I get English may be a second language but come on.